# Drupal 7 Taxonomy display parent

Tags: drupal, taxonomy, drupal-7

I was wondering if anyone might know how to get the taxonomy content pages in Drupal 7 to display their children's content as well.

For example given a vocabulary like:

```
-Animal
--Dog
--Cat
```

The Animal taxonomy page should display the dog and cats content as well.

Thank!

---

If it's any help, here's an exported copy of the view I'm using:

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'taxonomy_term';
$view->description = 'A view to emulate Drupal core\'s handling of taxonomy/term; it also emulates Views 1\'s handling by having two possible feeds.';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = '';
$view->core = 0;
$view->api_version = '3.0-alpha1';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Defaults */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node';
/* Sort criterion: Node: Sticky */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['sticky']['id'] = 'sticky';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['sticky']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['sticky']['field'] = 'sticky';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['sticky']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Sort criterion: Node: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Argument: Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['id'] = 'term_node_tid_depth';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['field'] = 'term_node_tid_depth';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_action'] = 'not found';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['style_plugin'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['title'] = '%1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['validate_type'] = 'taxonomy_term';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['validate_options']['type'] = 'tids';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['validate_options']['transform'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['depth'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['break_phrase'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['set_breadcrumb'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['use_taxonomy_term_path'] = 0;
/* Argument: Taxonomy: Term ID depth modifier */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['id'] = 'term_node_tid_depth_modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['field'] = 'term_node_tid_depth_modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['style_plugin'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
/* Filter: Node: Published or admin */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_extra']['id'] = 'status_extra';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_extra']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_extra']['field'] = 'status_extra';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_extra']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status_extra']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'taxonomy/term/%';

/* Display: Core feed */
$handler = $view->new_display('feed', 'Core feed', 'feed');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = 15;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'rss';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node_rss';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'taxonomy/term/%/%/feed';
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'page' => 'page',
  'default' => 0,
);

/* Display: Views 1 feed */
$handler = $view->new_display('feed', 'Views 1 feed', 'feed_1');
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = 15;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'rss';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node_rss';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'taxonomy/term/%/feed';
$translatables['taxonomy_term'] = array(
  t('Defaults'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort By'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('All'),
  t('%1'),
  t('Page'),
  t('Core feed'),
  t('Views 1 feed'),
);
```

Comment: How are the other options set? The block i'm generating displays nothing...

I've got a field taxonomy_term set up and a filter taxonomy_termid with depth.

Is a dropdown of the parents possible?

Thank you. Grtz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

Using the Views 'taxonomy_term' view, I set the Depth property of the 'Taxonomy: Term ID (with depth)' argument to the max (10.)

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for not using http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am but that doesn't really answer my question. (As far as I know) taxonomy menu doesn't change the way content is viewed by tag, it just creates menu's based on vocabularies.

Comment: Sorry, should read the question better, I thought this is about the menu. I think views can do this, but I'm not sure...